# airmon-ng not creating mon0 on kali linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

Whenever I try to use `airmon-ng start wlan0`, only the same thing as executing `airmon-ng check` happens, so mon0 isn't created.
Here are dumps of what happened, when I entered `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`:

`ifconfig`

> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>           inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
>           loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
>           RX packets 22  bytes 1316 (1.2 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 22  bytes 1316 (1.2 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> wlan0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>           ether 00:e0:4c:72:00:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

`iwconfig`

> wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
>             Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0
>             Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Encryption key:off
>             Power Management:off
>             Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
>             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>             Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.

If you need any more info to solve the problem, just ask

Answer (score 2):

Do your wireless chipset and drivers support monitor mode? You can check with this command:

`iw [your-wifi-adaptor-eg-phy0] info`

or this

`iw list`

if you're unsure.

Posting that info will help. Here's an example of a snippet from my output:

    `Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
         * mesh point`

As you can see, the chipset on my machine would support it.

Answer (score 0):

After checking using `iw list` and confirming it has monitor mode listed in there.

If monitor mode is listed then try `iw config wlan0 mode monitor` and this should put your wlan0 into monitor mode.

Comment: Here is how airmon-ng currently does it
https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/blob/87bf5727d99e21ce787c9d72a50237ce6b741f25/scripts/airmon-ng.linux#L472

Answer (score 0):

While i can only speak from Arch experience and not Kali, `airmon-ng start <interface name>` would cause the intended interface's [name](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html) to change to be `<interface name>mon` . E.g `wlan0mon` *(with 'mon' having then been postfixed to the original interface name)*

E.g if the interface intended to be used was named `wlp1s0u1u2` or `wlan0` , it would/should in most cases result in becoming/creating `wlp1s0u1u2mon` or `wlan0mon`, and not necessarily `mon0`.

(As documented on https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng)

> *"As you can see, it created a monitor mode interface called wlan0**mon**"*

(And from current [airmon-ng script source code](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/blob/87bf5727d99e21ce787c9d72a50237ce6b741f25/scripts/airmon-ng.linux#L472) effective line. *(regarding how it sets monitor mode)*)

> *iw phy ${PHYDEV} interface add ${1}**mon** type monitor*

which, depending on number of existing physical wifi devices and [naming convention](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html) used, *might* translate to something like:

> *iw phy `phy0` interface add `wlan0mon` type monitor*

*(In a case where `wlan0` is the physical wifi device `phy0`)

(snipped from `iw help` output)

```
    [iw] phy <phyname> interface add <name> type <type>
```

And although `mon0` could of course be set to be the *'name'* by running the command manually; It is not how the *airmon-ng* script does it..)*

Regardless, `ifconfig -a` aught to list **any** existing interfaces, and their names, even if they are "down"/inactive/turned off.

Other than that, [nonzyro's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1077522/633849) should first be tested, to check if the device even reports supporting [*monitor* mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode)

Comment: ..egg on my face for not realizing the question was over 4 years old..